# Twitter streaming API not getting all retweets

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-streaming-api, tweetstream, twitterapi-python

I'm using the streaming API to follow a specific user id, and I'm able to stream without any issues. However, when I compare all streamed tweets collected in one day to the ones collected with the rest API it seems that **the stream API missed some retweets**, i.e. tweets from the user id that somebody else retweeted.

I would've expected tweets from the rest API to be missing due to deleted content, but I can't understand why there would be missing tweets from the streaming.

I checked and I'm not hitting the rate limit (all tweets collected throughout the day are less than 200), the connection wasn't interrupted, I tried different days, and it is always around 25% missing retweets. No other types of tweets are missing.

Any help is much appreciated!!

```
class StreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def __init__(self, output_file=sys.stdout):
        super(StreamListener,self).__init__()

    def on_status(self, status):
        with open('tweets.json', 'a') as tf:

            json.dump(status._json, tf)    

            tf.write('\n')

        print(status.text)

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        if status_code == 420:
            return False


stream_listener = StreamListener()
stream = tweepy.Stream(auth=api.auth, listener=stream_listener)
stream.filter(follow=<id>)
```